# Problems with TransitionManager beginDelayedTransition for RecyclerView's item view

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

I have the following code:

```
class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...
    private Transition transition;

    ProductViewHolder(CardViewEx view) {
        super(view);

        ...
        transition = TransitionInflater.from(recyclerView.getContext())
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.price_button_transition);

        transition.addTarget(R.id.button_price)
            .addTarget(R.id.button_add_to_cart_or_customize)
            .addTarget(R.id.view_price);
    }

    void changePriceButton(int titleRes) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) itemView, transition);

        buttonPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setText(titleRes);
    }

    void resetPriceButton(boolean withTransition) {
        if (withTransition) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) itemView, transition);
        }
        buttonPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button_price)
    void onPriceClicked() {
        listener.onProductPriceClicked(product);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...

    resetPriceButton(false);
}


recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        resetPriceButtons();
    }
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {     
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    }
}


void resetPriceButtons() {

    int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; i++) {
        ProductViewHolder holder = (ProductViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);

        if (holder == null || holder.getLayoutPosition() != i) {
            // inconsistency
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        } else {
            holder.resetPriceButton(true);
        }
    }

    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, firstVisibleItemPosition);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(lastVisibleItemPosition + 1, getItemCount() - (lastVisibleItemPosition + 1));
}

void changePriceButton(long productId, int titleRes) {

    int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; i++) {
        ProductViewHolder holder = (ProductViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
        if (holder == null || holder.getLayoutPosition() != i) {
            // inconsistency
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        } else if (holder.product.getId() == productId) {
            holder.changePriceButton(titleRes, true);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, firstVisibleItemPosition);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(lastVisibleItemPosition + 1, getItemCount() - (lastVisibleItemPosition + 1));
    }
}
```

RecyclerView's item layout:

```
...
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_product"
            android:layout_width="64dp" android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/view_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <Button style="@style/Button.Border.Green"
                android:id="@+id/button_price"
                android:minWidth="76dp"/>
        <Button style="@style/Button.Flat.Green"
                android:id="@+id/button_add_to_cart_or_customize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="76dp"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_product"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_product" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view_price"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAllerRegular.13sp.Black87per"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to animate change price button to "Add to cart" when user clicks on the price, and back to the price when user starts scrolling RecyclerView.

When user clicks buttons and scroll recyclerview, button animations can stop in the middle state. You will see the margin between the right side of the window and the price button, or text "Add to cart" without the right padding on the button.
Then the button will be broken, you can try `changePriceButton/resetPriceButton` on it, but button won't show fully.

[image: Wrong UI state]

It is easy to reproduce this bug using "Animator duration scale" >= 5x.

It seems that `TransitionManager` has problems when you start `beginDelayedTransition` when there is `beginDelayedTransition` that already started on this view.
Also I think `TransitionManager` has problems with RecyclerView's view recycling on scrolling. Tried `TransitionManager.endTransitions((ViewGroup) itemView)` at the beginning of `onBindViewHolder`, but it didn't help.

The following solves the problem for me, but I am not sure fully.
Good to investigate the problem's reason.

I add the field `isResetPriceButton` in RecyclerView's holder for preventing attempts to change button to the same state when user starts scrolling RecycleView

```
private boolean isResetPriceButton;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    isResetPriceButton = false;
    ...
    resetPriceButton(false);
}

void changePriceButton(int titleRes) {

    if (isResetPriceButton) {
        isResetPriceButton = false;

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) itemView);

        buttonPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setText(titleRes);
    }
}

void resetPriceButton(boolean withTransition) {

    if (!isResetPriceButton) {
        isResetPriceButton = true;

        if (withTransition) {
            TransitionUtils.beginDelayedTransitionIfPossible((ViewGroup) itemView);
        }
        buttonPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonAddToCartOrCustomize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And I use the `setHasTransientState` on the holder's view during transition. But I don't like this, it produces extra views on scrolling when transitions have been started.

```
transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
        itemView.setHasTransientState(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        itemView.setHasTransientState(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
        itemView.setHasTransientState(false);
    }

    @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
    }

    @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {
    }
});
```